# How do you complete the lunar pillars on Terraria Console?

Tags: terraria-console

I’ve been trying to complete the lunar pillars but I keep dying to everything. I am a summoner. I use the optical staff (The twins minion) but I keep dying! I looked online to see which minion is the best but I need stardust fragments to get it.

Here is what I know, I have the beetle set, I have beat the vortex pillar, I use the optical staff, and how to get the stardust dragon staff.

What I do not know, I don’t know how to kill crawlipedes, and I don’t know if I should use a vortex beater

Can anyone tell me how to beat the rest of the pillars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to play summoner then consider using summoner specific armour like the spooky or tiki sets, since beetle armour has effects that benefit melee.

Other minion options pre-pillars would be raven or xeno staff. If you want the dragon then do the stardust pillar next.

To damage crawltipedes you have to hit the orange orb at the end of their tail, so use a weapon you can aim, since summons are unreliable.

*Basically just don't engage too many enemies at once and fall back before you get overwhelmed.*